# How to pass multiple enum types as method arguments and then call common methods on them?

Tags: java, enums

Our issue is like this: 
We want to pass different enum types to a method and call the values() method on the type.

```
public enum Testing {
    A, B, C, D
}

public enum Retesting {
    E, F, G, H
}

public static Object[] getValues(Enum e) {
    return e.values(); // ! Compilation Error
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Testing t = Testing.A;
    getValues(t);
}
```

Does anyone know if how something like this should be achieved or if it's possible at all?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what problem you want to solve. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: An enum is a *thing*. It has *a* value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all the enum values from enum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269803/getting-all-the-enum-values-from-enum-value)

Comment: It's possible. look at my answer. But `Enum e` here means that `e` is an instance of some enum, say `Testing.A`. Method `getValues(Class<? extends Enum<?> e)` would be more correct. Than you could write `e.getEnumConstants()`.

Comment: @korifey - Your answer is correct; you have to get the values from the class itself. This has already been asked and answered on SO which is why I voted to close as dup.

Comment: @Brian Roach Yeps, looks like duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using:

```
e.getClass().getEnumConstants()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using reflection.  But I like @korifey's answer better.  :)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T[] getValues(Class<T> e) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    return (T[]) e.getMethod("values").invoke(null);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(getValues(Testing.class)));
}
```

Comment: There's no such method as `values` in `Enum`. That would be the first problem the OP has ...

Answer (score 0):

Both @korifey and @Matt McHenry are right (+1 to each one). 
I personally think that in your case korifey's way is preferable.

I just wanted to add that your method signature may be:

getValues(Enum e) {
....
}

because all `enum`s are ordinary classes that extend class `Enum`;